# angularjs extension development kit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular application running, now some other team wants to add their module to my application and I don't want to change my existing application code. So, I am thinking of exposing some kind of xdk to that team so that they can build their own angular module add it to xdk and my application
which has xdk as its dependency, will check for any new module and automatically includes it inside my application.

I am thinking of this approach:

```
//json file with app details
{
    "app1": {
        appPath: 'app1.js',
        moduleName: 'app1Module'
    },
    "app2": {
        appPath: 'app2.js',
        moduleName: 'app2Module'
    }
}

//xdk app - no code change required
var basePath = 'https://path/to/cdn/<app_name>';
var xdkApp = angular.module('xdkApp', []);
/*
xhr to fetch json file and include all the available modules
*/

//main application - no code change required
var mainApp = angular.module['mainApp', [xdkApp]];
```

In this approach, another team will create their angular application and upload their code to cdn and update that entry into json file. In xdk application
I will make xhr request to that json file which will read all the dependencies and load all the required modules due to which code of my application and
the xdk application would not get changed.

Disadvantage:
- It will increase xhr requests to fetch the app.js, which eventually will increase loading time

So is there any better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Depending on whatever build process you use can do it then also, the same way you import whatever other external modules you use

Comment: Can you share some reference ?

Comment: Do you use a build process...grunt, gulp, webpack etc?

Comment: I am using webpack